# ReactJS imported css does not work - inline css in combination with JSX is working

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

So I have a simple react component and I'm really new to the whole web world.
I have done the following...

CharacterForm.js

```
    const segmentStyle = {
      margin: "3% 3% 5% 3%",
      padding: "3%",
      
    }

<Segment style={segmentStyle}>
....
</Segment>
```

The `Segment` tag is from react [semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/segment/)

This worked fine. After some more lines of code I realized I want to do more "complex" styling and created a css which I import like this into my .js:

```
import "./CharacterForm.css";
```

So my Code is now like this...

CharacterForm.js:

```
import "./CharacterForm.css";
<Segment className="segment">
...
</Segment>
```

CharacterForm.css

```
.segment {
    margin: 3% 3% 5% 3%;
    padding: 3%;
}
```

But this move just removed the margin and padding and it is like it was unstyled. I was expecting to stay styled with the assigned margin and padding value.

I have also imported "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css" like mentioned in the official documentation. The object are rendering but without the imported css.

I have also done this (external css) with my navigation bar component and everything worked as expected with imported css.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some typos in the code, syle -> style and Import -> import

Comment: Are you sure Webpack isn't encoding your classes? If you go into dev tools in the browser does it still say `class="segment"`?

Comment: @DeanJames yes it does

Comment: Must be something else - I have tested this and it works fine on sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dirac-q7410

Comment: went more weird now. I set everything back to the inline css -> it worked. Switched back to external css -> it worked. Did the same again and it does not work anymore on external css. Does not matter if I let the code compile again or reload site or anything like that. Web development is weird for beginners but I wanna understand :D

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose such problems. What I would recommend you do is use css modules rather than rely on classes. I've updated the example I linked before to use this approach. Basically import the css file, then reference the import by name. This should prevent any compilers or encoders from chewing up your references!